# How to flag ridiculous upvotes - or should we just ignore them

Tags: discussion

Pretty often I see low quality questions being upvoted as soon as they are posted. I suspect that it is something like "buddies upvoting each other". I can't be sure, though.

I wonder if we should do anything about such upvotes.

What - if anything - should one do when something like that is observed?

Answer (score 5):

Do flag those for moderator attention; use the 'other' flag and explain why you think there might be something suspicious going on.

We moderators will then investigate and see if anything is indeed amiss and take action accordingly.